# How Do I get back the Login Sound? (Playing in Guest Account Though!)

Tags: 11.10, sound, login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No startup sound in ubuntu 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90009/no-startup-sound-in-ubuntu-11-10)

My Ubuntu 11.10 was having login Sound after I installed it. But, after few days, the sound is not playing!

However, the sound is heard when logged on using Guest account, the sound is being played!

I could not hear the sound on Administrator Account.

Answer (score 2):

In Terminal, run:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/* /usr/share/sounds/
```

Restart, and login sound and any other sounds you have enabled, should be back.

Answer (score 1):

Open up the "Startup Applications" application, and ensure that the "Gnome Login Sound" is selected.

Comment: I want to comment to the answer that has already been given, but don't know how. In 11.10 the "Startup Applications" is completely empty until you add things to it. I Assume this is because it is not showing the start up processes that the system uses. Probably in an attempt to prevent users from messing up their systems. But if they are going to keep changing things like this, shouldn't there be a statement or something saying to the more experienced uses, "Hey everyone, we are going to be changing [x, y, and z] in the upcoming release. The features will still be there, just a little harder t

Comment: Hmmmm ... mine was not empty. I'll check on a machine with a fresh install.

Comment: It is selected.. Yet again I could not hear the sound!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this as it worked for me, first download `dconf-editor` from software center, then run it, go to `org/gnome/desktop/application/sound`, then point your cursor to `event-sounds` and below dconf editor there is **set to default** button, click it,and log out and login from your account, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

go to your home directory, hit ctrl+h to display hidden folders then delete the .pulse directory. after logoff and logon the .pulse directory automatically recreate.
this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Install dconf editor.

Go to

```
org->gnome->desktop->sound
Change the the sound theme "freedesktop" to ubuntu
```

(small letters)

Log out and login again.