# Is it possible to enable sound for Login and Logout?

Tags: login

Is it possible to enable sound for Login and Logout (like windows) in ubuntu 11.10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ubuntu, the login sound should be enabled by default, if not, go to *System* => *Preferences* => *Startup Applications*.
There you should find the option GNOME Login Sound. Enable it and you get a sound whenever you login.
If that doesn't work, look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90009/no-startup-sound-in-ubuntu-11-10).

For shutdown, [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106212/i-lost-my-shutdown-sound) could help.