# I lost my shutdown sound

Tags: sound, shutdown, logout

I lost both my startup and shutdown sounds. I restored the startup sound adding it to Startup programs, but I don't know how to restore my shudown sound. I checked if the sound file is in /usr/share/sounds/ and there it is... So, any help, please?

Comment: there are same Problem on my System... No Logout Sound will playing. all Files are present, but not sound will playing after "Logout" ... What can i do more? ty Lupo

Answer (score 1):

You can try running `dconf-editor` and setting the value of **org/gnome/desktop/application/sound** to **ubuntu**.
Like in the following screenshot:
[image]

Worked for me when I had the same problem.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work for me. And when I login after try freedesktop is restored as theme-name.

Comment: @Pepe After modifying in dconf-editor, can you open the sound panel and see if Default is selected?

Comment: Do you mean the default sound alert? It is.

Comment: I restarted twice the system and I looks that the ubuntu theme is set, but still there's no shutdown sound.