# Ubuntu starting with mute sound

Tags: sound

My Ubuntu is staring with the "speaker" signal in the alsa-mixer. Everytime I boot my computer I have to go there and uncheck the "mute" checkbox. How can I make it unmute automatically so that I don't have to do it manually everytime?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi I've found something helpful to you . please look at this 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/90009/no-startup-sound-in-ubuntu-11-10

Comment: thanks for your help, but the problem is different from the other question. I don't head the login sound and all the others too. All the sound is muted.

Comment: This happens to me as well, but it always seems to be sporadic when it does. Usually, I've found that if I had my laptop's volume muted before shutting down, it is muted on startup. I don't know if the correlation is there for you too, but that's what happens for me.

Comment: I also thinks this is not everytime that happens, but most of the times it does. However, I has happened several times that the sound was not muted, and after a reboot it was.

Answer (score 1):

You should file a bug report. [Instructions here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

A simple workaround is to add this line into your .profile which will run every time you log on. If you don't want to set it to 50% volume, you can adjust your volume level you want it, and then check to see what it is by running:

```
alsa-mixer
```

Then, to test it out, play some music, and run the next line of code. You can play around witht the % just to make sure it's working for you.

```
amixer set Master 50%
```

The next line is supposed to keep the volumes at your prescribed levels, but I've found that it doesn't always work.

```
sudo alsactl store Master 50%
```

So, to make it set every time you log in, add it to your .profile

```
echo 'amixer set Master 50%' >> ~/.profile
```

Comment: Was trying to figure out the solution for my headphone muting problem happening with every boot. Your solution worked like a charm on Ubuntu 15.10. Thanks.